# universal "/success" that shows message if added

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem and I don't know if it's possible but I'm going to ask here.
I have rewrite rules like this:

```
    RewriteRule ^login$ index.php?page=login [NC]
```

and I want to do something like this, if you add "/success" then the url will look something like this:

```
 "mydomain.com/login/success"
```

and that will add a $_GET variable to the url and the original url will be:

```
"index.php?page=login&status=success".
```

I want to be able to add /success to every page that I have, example: mydomain.com/register/success and so on..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Allright, first thing:
**This is not how URI Rewrite works. Sorry man but you really need to study a bit more on the topic.**

To solve your issue you need to:

1. Get the URI using PHP Global Vars
2. Process it and extract your parameters

There is no way .htaccess will be able to do what you are looking for. I don't usually post my stuff, but i suggest you to read some of the source code of a project i've been working on a few months to understand how routing works. [URLParser Example here](https://github.com/jnardiello/Blast/blob/master/http/lib/URLParser.class.php)

Unfortunately to properly understand my code you have a minimal notion of MVC. Hope it helps!